# Getting CSS from Angular element in custom directive using dynamic class name

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a custom directive that makes use of the background color of the element in the link function:

```
.directive('ktMouseover', function($log) {
  return {
    restrict: "AC",
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
      if ($(".ie8, .ie7").length === 0) {
        console.log(elm.attr("class"));
        var oldBackgroundColor = elm.css("background-color") || elm.css("background")
          , colors = attrs["ktMouseover"].split("|")[0] || "#fec|#f55"
          , timings = attrs["ktMouseover"].split("|")[1] || "75|150"
          , newBackgroundColor = colors.split(":")[0] || "#fec"
          , newDangerColor = colors.split(":")[1] || "#f55"
          , fadeInTime = parseInt(timings.split(":")[0]) || 75
          , fadeOutTime = parseInt(timings.split(":")[1]) || 150;

        elm.mouseenter(function() {
          if (elm.hasClass("inactive")) return;
          $(this).animate({
            "backgroundColor":($(this).hasClass("danger") ? newDangerColor : newBackgroundColor)
          }, fadeInTime);
        }).mouseleave(function() {
          $(this).animate({
            "backgroundColor": (oldBackgroundColor ? oldBackgroundColor : "transparent")
          }, fadeOutTime);
        });
      }
    }
  };
})
```

HTML snippet:

```
        <li class="{{child.type()}}"
            ng-include="'/partials/tree.html'"
            id="container_{{child.id()}}" 
            kt-mouseover=":#f55|75:150" 
            ng-click="getChildren(child)" 
            ng-repeat="child in vault.children()">
        </li>
```

When I initially coded this, I was using a static class name for the tag (and that's how the background-color is set in my css). Now I have a need for these directives to have a dynamic class name, which suddenly makes it impossible to grab the background-color from the element, as the class name hasn't been applied to it yet.

How do I accomplish this idiomatically in AngularJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare the oldBackgroundColor variable without initializing it and set it in the mouseenter the first time. I don't know if that is really the best way to go about it, but it works:

```
.directive('ktMouseover', function($log) {
  return {
    restrict: "AC",
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
      if ($(".ie8, .ie7").length === 0) {

        // ***NOT INITIALIZED***
        var oldBackgroundColor
          , colors = attrs["ktMouseover"].split("|")[0] || "#fec|#f55"
          , timings = attrs["ktMouseover"].split("|")[1] || "75|150"
          , newBackgroundColor = colors.split(":")[0] || "#fec"
          , newDangerColor = colors.split(":")[1] || "#f55"
          , fadeInTime = parseInt(timings.split(":")[0]) || 75
          , fadeOutTime = parseInt(timings.split(":")[1]) || 150;

        elm.mouseenter(function() {
          if (elm.hasClass("inactive")) return;

          // ***INITIALIZED HERE INSTEAD***
          if (!oldBackgroundColor) oldBackgroundColor  = elm.css("background-color") || elm.css("background");
          $(this).animate({
            "backgroundColor":($(this).hasClass("danger") ? newDangerColor : newBackgroundColor)
          }, fadeInTime);
        }).mouseleave(function() {
          $(this).animate({
            "backgroundColor": (oldBackgroundColor ? oldBackgroundColor : "transparent")
          }, fadeOutTime);
        });
      }
    }
  };
})
```